# Problema: conflicting requests when installing odoo in Fedora 32

Tags: odoo, fedora

I'm trying to install odoo 11 in fedora 32 but I get these errors:

> Problema: conflicting requests
>
> - nothing provides pychart needed by odoo-11.0.post20191021-1.noarch
> - nothing provides pyparsing needed by odoo-11.0.post20191021-1.noarch
> - nothing provides libxslt-python needed by odoo-11.0.post20191021-1.noarch

The steps I've followed are:

1. Install postgresql & intiate the service
2. $ sudo yum localinstall https://nightly.odoo.com/11.0/nightly/rpm/odoo_11.0.20191021.noarch.rpm

It seems there are python dependencies that can't be installed but I don't know how can I install them.

Do you have any idea how can I fix this problem? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the installation packages is not working for you, you can always run Odoo server from the source.

Create a virtual environment for your Odoo app, let's call it `venv11`.

Get Odoo source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git --depth 1 -b 11.0
```

Activate virtual environment. Install `Python3` packages using pip.

```
pip install -r odoo/requirements.txt
```

Make sure you have installed the `dev` libraries needed for some of the `pip` packages that needs to be compiled, you will face `xxxx.h` not found error, you have search for that library and install using your distro package manager.

After your pip package installation is complete you can generate config file for your Odoo server using following command

```
python odoo/odoo-bin -c odoo.conf --save --stop-after-init
```

Edit the config file to add some important configuration, for example, `db_user, db_password, http_port`.
Now that you have added DB connection details, your Odoo application can now connect with your Postgresql Database and you can start using Odoo application by creating new database. If you don't have Postgresql information, you can just switch to `postgres` user and create new user with super user access.

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
create user `username` with superuser;
alter user `username` with encrypted password 'password';
```

and add those information to the config file. Now you can run Odoo server using

```
python odoo/odoo-bin -c odoo.conf
```

Head back to browser, browse `127.0.0.1:8069` 8069 is the default port but you can change it from the config file. The database creation web interface will appear and you can start using Odoo application.

> ** Note: run python commands in virtual environment activated as that will isolate pip packages.

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for your quick answer! Now I get this error: 'File "/home/osboxes/environments/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/relativedelta.py", line 118

    raise TypeError, "relativedelta only diffs datetime/date"

                   ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax.' when doing 'python odoo/odoo-bin -c odoo.conf --save –stop-after-init'. Do you know why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is a Python2 syntax error, run python -V and paste the result here. Have you activated the virtual environment before running `python odoo/odoo-bin -c odoo.conf --save –stop-after-init` command?